# How to calculate the LR value when ARMv7-A architecture implementation takes an IRQ exception

Tags: arm, interrupt-handling, armv7, irq

I'm researching the the **Arm Architecture Reference Manual ARMv7-A ARMv7-R edition** document these days. When I read about the exception handling part of this manual, it comes across a confusions to me.  **The problem is about how to decide the LR value when ARMv7-A architecture implementation takes an IRQ exception**.

EXAMPLE: Suppose that the processor is executing an instruction at the address of 0x_0000_1000 and an IRQ is taken.First, we have to calculate some parameters to be used to calculate the LR.

1. **preferred return address**,which is the Address of next instruction to execute in this case. So **preferred return address = 0x_0000_1002** in thumb instruction set or **preferred return address = 0x_0000_1004** for arm instruction set.[preferred return address for the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qljjh.png)
2. **PC**,which is the program counter and holds the current program address.In this case, **PC = 0x_0000_1004** in thumb instruction state or **PC = 0x_0000_1008** in arm instruction state.[how to calculate PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL7IH.png)

Then, here are 2 methods mentioned in the document to decide the LR value when taking this IRQ exception.

1. by using **preferred return address**. **LR** = **preferred return address** + **offset** that depends on the instruction set state when the exception was taken.In this case **LR = 0x_0000_1002 + 4** in thumb instruction state or **LR = 0x_0000_1004 + 4** in arm instruction state.[Offsets applied to Link value for exceptions taken to PL1 modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD1Az.png)
2. by using **PC**. **LR = PC-0** if in thumb instruction set or **LR = PC-4** when in arm instruction set.In this case **LR = 0x_0000_1004 - 0** in thumb instruction set or **LR = 0x_0000_1008 - 4** in arm instruction state. [Pseudocode description of taking the IRQ exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS2C5.png)

**Problem**:the LR results calculated by the 2 methods are **different** both in thumb set state and arm set state(with **first method** we get **LR = 0x_0000_1006 or LR = 0x_0000_1008**,but **second method** we get **LR = 0x_0000_1004 or LR = 0x_0000_1004**). which one is correct or is there any wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - the IRQ `LR` will point to the next instruction to complete work as would normally be run without an interrupt.  Otherwise, code would not execute the same in the presence of interrupts.

It is confusing as the ARM documents may refer to `PC` in many different contexts and they are not the same.

---

> EXAMPLE:Suppose that the processor is executing an instruction at the address of 0x_0000_1000 and an IRQ is taken.  First, we have to calculate some parameters to be used to calculate the LR.
>
> preferred return address,which is the Address of next instruction to execute in this case. So preferred return address = 0x_0000_1002 in thumb instruction set or preferred return address = 0x_0000_1004 for arm instruction set.preferred return address for the exception

This is not correct.  The ARM cpu has a pipeline and the last instruction that it has deemed to have completed is the *next instruction*.  Take for example this sequence,

```
     0: cmp r1, #42
     1: bne 4f          ; interrupt happens as this completes.
     2: add r2, r2, #4
     3: b   5f
     4: sub r2, r2, #2
     5: ; more code.
```

If the interrupt happens as label '1:' happens, the next instruction will be either '2:' or '4:'.  If you followed your rule this would either increase interrupt latency by never allowing an interrupt in such cases, or interrupts would cause incorrect code.  Specifically, your link says *next instruction to execute*.

> PC,which is the program counter and holds the current program address.In this case, PC = 0x_0000_1004 in thumb instruction state or PC = 0x_0000_1008 in arm instruction state.how to calculate PC

Here you are mixing concepts.  One is when you use a value like `ldr r0, [pc, #42]`.  When you calculate the offset, you must add two to the current `ldr` instruction.  The actual `PC` is not necessarily this value.  At some point (original version), the ARM was a two stage pipeline.  In order to keep behaviour the same, subsequent ARM cpus follow the rule of being two ahead when calculating `ldr r0, [pc, #42]` type addresses.  However, the actual PC may be much different inside the CPU.  The concept above describes the programmer visible `PC` for use with addressing.

The CPU will make a decision, sometimes base on configuration, on what work to complete.  For instance, `ldm sp!, {r0-r12}` may take some time to complete.  The CPU may decide to abort this instruction to keep interrupt latency low.  Alternatively, it may perform 12 memory reads which could have wait states.  The `LR_irq` will be set to the `ldm` instruction or the next instruction depending whether it is aborted or not.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "The ARM cpu has a pipeline and the last instruction that it has deemed to have completed is the next instruction." I know that pipeline mechanism of arm architecture,and the PC = CURRENT EXCUTING instruction + 4 or +8 is the result of this pipeline. But I don't understand "the last instruction it has completed is the next instruction". from what i understand,the next instruction means the instruction to be excuted next,and the pc is the address of instruction to be prefetched.

Comment: No, it is no +4 or +8.  Read “Here you are mixing concepts”. The pipe maybe 10 instructions on some cpus.  It is definitely different across arm cpus.

Comment: I get that, you mean there are two aspects view of this behavior, 1)programmer's view , 2)system's view. For a behavior, system's view may be very different from the programmer's view.But we just have to obey the programmer's view of the architecture because system's view is just for compiler designers or architecture designers,and it may take Forwards Compatibility into the design.

Comment: Right, but the documents are talking about the system PC, not the programmer PC.  That is a key point.  For your calculations/assumption this matters.